# Find only subset that sum to a particular value in java

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I have a TreeMap in which I have keys and all its values and a target value.Below is my approach. It's basically to find a subset. But here i need the keys of the values which sum to the target. I have done a recursion approach. Here I want to end the recursion if I get any one subset. Is there any optimal way to solve this? Note :- The values will be much bigger and I will have hundreds of data.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SubsetFromATree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<Integer,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>() ;
        tm.put(0, 3);
        tm.put(1, 4);
        tm.put(2, 5);
        tm.put(3, 6);
//      for(int i =0;i<20;i++) {
//          tm.put(i, i+1);
//      }
        ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("0");
        subset(tm,10,out,tm.size(),s,ans);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    private static void subset(TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm, int tsum, ArrayList<Integer> out, int size, StringBuffer val,
            ArrayList<Integer> ans) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(tsum == 0) {
            val.append("1");
            for(int i = 0;i<out.size();i++) {
                ans.add(out.get(i));
            }
            return;
        }
        if(size == 0 || val.equals("1")) {
            return;
        }
        //Not including
        subset(tm,tsum,out,size-1,val,ans);
        ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>(out);
        output.add(tm.get(size-1));
        subset(tm,tsum-tm.get(size-1),output,size-1,val,ans);
        return;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no efficient way to solve this; [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is NP-complete and will take exponential time.

Comment: Isn't there any way that if the we achieve the target sum, from there we end all the recursion?

Comment: That's certainly doable, yes.  For example, you could return a `boolean` indicating whether or not you've found a valid solution, instead of having a `void` function.

Comment: For this I tried to use a StringBuffer so that if val becomes 1 it will end the recursion but that isn't working.

Comment: `val.equals("1")` will never be true because a `StringBuffer` is not equal to a `String`.